# Adding every 3rd row in a Column Macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Sum every 3rd row in column "K", starting from K2 to the last cells used. Please note, the data or cells used in column "K" will vary.

I need a macro to sum the values in every 3rd row til the last row used and show the Total in "M1".

I attached a snapshot of some sample values and what I would like the end result to look like.

[image]

Comment: Also this can be done with a formula.

Comment: I just have simple code to sum the values. I have tried to use the MOD formula but I have been unsuccessful. Here is the code I currently have for the sum of column "K":                                                         
                                                                                                           Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
Dim Lastrow As Long


Range("M1").Value = Application.Sum(Range("K2:K" & Lastrow))


End Sub

Comment: Post the code (or formula) that you tried **into the question**. (It's almost impossible to read in a comment, and comments may be deleted which then makes the question useless.) It shouldn't be hard to fix your `Mod` so that it works.

Comment: This is the formula I used.  =SUM(--(MOD(ROW(1:28),3)=0),(K1:K28))

Comment: Please note, I need this to be in VBA form.

Comment: Do you mean to add only the negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Short and slow (tested and in Excel it works only as an array formula):

```
[M1] = [SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(K:K),3)=1,K:K))]
```

or a bit longer by limiting the range:

```
[M1] = Evaluate(Replace("SUM(K2:K9*(MOD(ROW(2:9),3)=1))", 9, [K1].End(xlDown).Row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Howdee Tom - This should do the trick for you.

```
Sub Sum_Every_Third()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, amount As Long

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Be sure to change to your correct sheet name

lastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

amount = 0
For i = 2 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 13).Offset(-1, 0).Row Mod 3 = 0 Then ' Make sure you change 13 to your column number
    amount = amount + Cells(i, 13).Value
End If
Next i

MsgBox amount

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Wolfie and Clouse24 both worked as needed! Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0):

This sub should achieve your summing, see comments for details

```
Sub dosum()
    ' Get last row
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row
    ' Assign range object to data in column K
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K" & lastrow)
    ' Sum every third item
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mySum As Double
    mySum = 0
    ' Step through cells in range, 3 at a time
    For i = 3 To myRange.Cells.Count Step 3
        mySum = mySum + myRange.Cells(i).Value
    Next I
    ' Put in cell 
    ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value = mySum
End Sub
```